# difference between -s and my implementation

Tags: perl, file, loops

Having this snippet:

```
my $file = "input.txt"; # let's assume that this is an ascii file

my $size1 = -s $file;
print "$size1\n";

$size2 = 0;
open F, $file;
$size2 += length($_) while (<F>);
close F;
print "$size2\n";
```

when can one assert that it is true that `$size1` equals `$size2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as `Lee Duhem` says, the two numbers may be different because of Perl's end-of-line processing, or because [`length`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/length.html) reports the size of the string in *characters*, which will throw the numbers out if there are any wide characters in the text.

However the [`tell`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tell.html) function will report the exact position *in bytes* that you have read up to, so an equivalent to your program for which the numbers *are* guaranteed to match is this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = 'input.txt';

my $size1 = -s $file;
print "$size1\n";

open my $fh, '<', $file or die $!;
my $size2 = 0;
while (<$fh>) {
  $size2 = tell $fh;
}
close $fh;

print "$size2\n";
```

Please note the use of `use strict` and `use warnings`, the lexical file handle, the three-parameter form of `open`, and the check that it succeeded. All of these are best-practice for Perl programs and should be used in *everything* you write

Comment: Re "which will throw the numbers out if there are any wide characters in the text", In the OP's example, that can happen if `-C` or `-Mopen=...` is used (directory, or via env var `PERL5OPTS`), or if env var `PERLIO` is used.

Comment: @ikegami: Thanks. (Do you mean *directly*?)

Comment: yup, typo. "directly, or via env var `PERL5OPTS`".

Answer (score 3):

You cannot, because the input layer may do some convert on the input line, for example change `crlf` to `cr`, that may change the length of that line.

In addition, `length $line` count how many characters in `$line`, in the multi-byte encoding, as the example given by @choroba, one character may occupy more than one bytes.

See [`perlio`](http://perldoc.perl.org/PerlIO.html) for further details.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't specify an encoding that supports multibyte characters, it should hold. Otherwise, the result can be different:

```
$ cat 1.txt
žluťoučký kůň

$ perl -E 'say -s "1.txt";
           open my $FH, "<:utf8", "1.txt";
           my $f = do { local $/; <$FH> };
           say length $f;'

20
14
```

Comment: According to Google, that says *"publish horse"*!

Comment: @Borodin: *Yellow horse* is a better translation :)

Answer (score 1):

You're simply missing `binmode(F);` or the `:raw` IO layer. These cause Perl to return the file exactly as it appears on disk. No line ending translation. No decoding of character encodings.

```
open(my $fh, '<:raw', $file)
   or die "open $file: $!\n");
```

Then your code works fine.

```
my $size = 0;
$size += length while <$fh>;
```

That's not particularly good because it could read the entire file at once for binary files. So let's read fixed-sized blocks instead.

```
local $/ = \(64*1024);
my $size = 0;
$size += length while <$fh>;
```

That's basically the same as using `read`, which reads 4K or 8K (in newer Perls) at a time. There are performance benefits to reading more than that at a time, and we can use `sysread` to do that.

```
my $size = 0;
while (my $bytes_read = sysread($fh, my $buf, 64*1024)) {
   $size += $bytes_read;
}
```

Reading the whole file is silly, though. You could just seek to the end of the file.

```
use Fcntl qw( SEEK_END );

my $size = sysseek($fh, 0, SEEK_END);
```

But then again, you might as well just use `-s`.

```
my $size = -s $fh;
```